# E: The package ubuntu-mono needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management

I installed Ubuntu 16.04
I'm getting this error:

```
E: The package ubuntu-mono needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I haven't found the solution. What should I do?

Comment: What were you doing prior to that error?

Comment: I was trying to install office 2013 using play on Linux 
and I was facing a problem and that problem lead to this error :(

Comment: but it's different from my problem ....

Comment: No, it's the exact same thing. Start by checking the repositories and enable what is eventually disabled. Then do (in terminal) `sudo apt update`. Then try `sudo apt install ubuntu-mono`. If errors, please edit your question and post the full error messages along with the steps that triggered the original error.

Comment: ok....
I start it by using this command 
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all hl1440lpr
and I got this message ..
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove hl1440lpr which isn't installed

Comment: Don't follow it exactly. You need to replace the package names with the one affecting you.

Answer (score 45):

I Found The Solution
FINALLY....
first, open the terminal and write this command:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all ubuntu-mono
```

after that, write this command

```
sudo apt-get update
```