# linux-headers-5.4.0-56 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: kernel

I can't do most things with the Terminal because it gives me this error: "the package linux-headers-5.4.0-56 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."
I have tried to do things like: `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-5.4.0-56 linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic`

But it still outputs the same error.
I have also tried to simply update my Ubuntu but whenever I try to open the Software Updater It simply does nothing.
Doing: `Sudo apt-get upgrade` Gives the same error.

Comment: That kernel was deleted from the repos because it had issues. See https://askubuntu.com/q/1299090/243321 That's why your system can't find it. Suggest you remove everything related to that kernel (unless it's the one you are using).

Comment: When running ```uname -r``` It says: i'm using: 5.4.0-54-generic. Do I need to update my kernel to a new version? if so how do I do that?

Comment: If you have bionic-updates enabled, `linux-headers-generic` should point to `linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic` which would pull .58 kernel. You can refer [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1299504/816190) to know how to remove .56.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else ends up here. The solution to  [E: The package ubuntu-mono needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868064/e-the-package-ubuntu-mono-needs-to-be-reinstalled-but-i-cant-find-an-archive#answer-868227) gave me something that helped me move the obstacle away:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

Boot some recent kernel that is not 5.4.0-56.
Then install my *linux-purge* script from [here](https://launchpad.net/linux-purge) and run

```
sudo linux-purge --choose
```

And choose the 5.4.0-56 kernel(s) and purge. Thereafer update to install the latest kernel. Reboot.