# linux-headers-5.4.0-56 generic

Tags: 20.04, kernel, linux-headers

Is there any solution for this "Error: E:The package linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it." I can't do anything...just whatever I do or any updating show me this message. This is my third post regarding this.

Comment: The usual solution is, as the error message suggests, to reinstall the package before doing anything else. Since the package is no longer available using `apt`, you must get it from someplace else. launchpad.net is the normal place to get old packages from.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to remove the problematic package by

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic
```

or in low-level

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic
```

Then install normal latest kernel and its headers using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303046/linux-headers-5-4-0-56-needs-to-be-reinstalled-but-i-cant-find-an-archive-for

Comment: At last... @N0rbert thanks for your answer.. it worked.

Comment: Great, so you can accept it :)